# How to add postgreSQL in corda?

Tags: postgresql, corda

Error while running the node

[image]

- Added postgresql-42.1.4.jar in PartyA/node/drivers folder
- Edited node.config file with postgreSQL properties

```
dataSourceProperties = {
dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"
dataSource.user = "postgres"
dataSource.password = "ad123"
}
database = {
 transactionIsolationLevel = "READ_COMMITTED"
}
jarDirs :['PartyA/node/drivers']
```

Comment: What is the version of Postgres you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct credentials to connect to the database.

More details on Connecting to Postgres can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html#postgresql

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you confirm that PostgresSQL is properly installed: `psql --version`.
2. Can you confirm that you can connect to `postgres` using username `postgres` and password `ad123`: `psql -h host -U username databasename` (i.e. `psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres`).
3. **Most Importantly!** Did you follow [these steps](https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-database-developer.html#postgresql) to create a schema for your node?

```
CREATE USER "my_user" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_password';
CREATE SCHEMA "my_schema";
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA "my_schema" TO "my_user";
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON ALL tables IN SCHEMA "my_schema" TO "my_user";
ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA "my_schema" GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON tables TO "my_user";
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL sequences IN SCHEMA "my_schema" TO "my_user";
ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA "my_schema" GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON sequences TO "my_user";
ALTER ROLE "my_user" SET search_path = "my_schema";
```